# Logging all the commands executed during a kickstart installation to file and screen

Tags: logging, kickstart, options

I'm using the following kickstart post installation logging options:

```
%post  
exec < /dev/tty3 > /dev/tty3  
chvt 3  
echo  
echo "################################"  
echo "# Running Post Configuration #"  
echo "################################"  
(  
  echo 'Hello, World!'  
  cat > test_file <<EOF  
  Hello World  
  EOF  
) 2>&1 | /usr/bin/tee /var/log/post_install.log  
chvt 1
```

The problem is that I'm not actually capturing commands used to create the test_file (code beginning with cat and ending with EOF) in my log file.  The echo statement is there but nothing more.

The following code solves the problem but will mean I have to append a tee statement to all of my post installation procedures, which is not satisfactory.

```
echo -e "# Writing test_file and capturing to log_file" && /usr/bin/tee -ai log_file >> test_file << EOF  
Hello World  
EOF
```

The current log file created only captures echo statement which is not enough.  I want to capture the commands executed complete with their associated options and arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Post can automatically log:

```
%post --log=/root/kickstart-post.log
```

And running

```
set -x
```

should log all executed commands and arguments.